# MS Access create forms for distinct field value in VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, distinct

I have a VBA script and I need to create forms based on distinct LocationIDs in a table. So for every row with LocationID = 1 create a form with the name of that location represented in the title of the form, "formLocation1". Then for each LocationID = 2, create another form with the name of that one in the title, "formLocation2", etc. What is the best way to do this using DoCmd.OpenForm"" in the VBA script?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Loop through a recordset, and create a form for each *LocationID* using the [CreateForm()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-createform-method-access) method. You can then set the Form's `.Caption` property to "formLocation(LocationID)".

(Change `T` to the name of your table).

```
Public Sub CreateForms()
    On Error GoTo ex

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT LocationID FROM T ORDER BY LocationID;", dbOpenSnapshot)

    With rs
        If .EOF Then GoTo out
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    Dim frm As Access.Form, i As Integer
    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount

        Set frm = CreateForm()
            frm.Caption = "formLocation" & rs![LocationID]

        DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name, acSaveYes
        Set frm = Nothing

        rs.MoveNext
    Next i

out:
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ex:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume out
End Sub
```